# What is the best practice for unit testing private methods in .NET?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, design-patterns, reflection, accessor

Recently in order to implement unit testing for a private method of a class, I used  PrivateObject by **creating a private accessors instead of using Reflection**, to which I received the following code review comment:

> "My main concern with Private Object is the use of object[] in constructor.  It replaces  strong typing enforced by compiler with JavaScript-style run-time error detection.Consequently , personally, I would not recommend it."

This comment above confused me beacuse as per my understanding, Reflection also needs the `object[]` to invoke any method. Please help me to understand what the best approach is.

Answer (score 6):

- You can use special classes that
  inherit classes with private (now
  protected) methods and provide public
  methods that call invisible from
  outside protected methods.

This is called Test Specific Subclass or Test Specific Extension in great book Refactoring Test Code http://xunitpatterns.com/

You can read more details and ideas for testing private methods here : http://xunitpatterns.com/Test-Specific%20Subclass.html

It works like

```
public TestClass : RealClass
{
    public int  CallHiddenCalculate()
    {
        return  Calculate(); // Calculate is now protected method that we expose for test purposes in this class
    }
}
```

You can place this class to test assembly so your real assembly doesnt contain test specific logic and classes because its bad design.

- You can also use conditional compilation for visibility attribute like the following

```
    #if DEBUG
        public
    #else
        private
    #endif
```

In this case in Debug you can call unit tests but in release those methods won't be visible.
However this approach is much worse than the above and is more ugly too.

Testing just public interface can easily be not enough (and often is not) in order to say that you got good test coverage and your code is easy to maintain and refactor.

As for marking private methods as internal and having test assembly see internal methods is bad for many reasons

1. your ex private methods are visible
   from your assembly cause they are
   internal
2. you will have test specific logic
   (internal for those methods will
   only be for test purposes) in
   release version of your product,
   which is bad

and I think there are more but those are most important

Comment: +1 - I like it!  This can be extended to protected accessors, too!  I learned a useful technique today.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question.  Generally, unit tests are meant to verify the public behavior of your classes, from the viewpoint of consumers of your classes.  That is, the consumers don't care HOW you do it, so long as your class keeps the promises it makes.

If you REALLY need to expose 'private' members to unit test, mark them as internal and make them accessible via the InternalsVisibleTo attribute.  It's ugly, but it works, and you can later keep it out of your assembly with some conditional compilation.

Comment: ... Of course, marking properties, accessors, and methods as internal means that you fully trust another developer (or your future self) to be disciplined about using these when working within your assembly =)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I cannot avoid testing private methods its is the requirement. so wanted to chose between reflection and PrivateObject with proper understanding

Comment: @Chirag - if you have unit tested all your public methods, your private methods are implicitly tested to. Those private methods that don't get covered by your unit tests are redundant and should be removed. Your requirement of testing the private methods *can* be fullfilled by testing the public methods. If the requirement is that your should explicitly *call* the private methods in a unit test, the requirements are wrong *(my point of view)*.

Comment: @Lieven this is usually wrong approach, implicit tests of private methods are pretty close to testing program by using UI compared to real unit tests that test small methods. Lets say you got a Class with 1 big method that has 5 parameters and inside it contains 20 private methods that manipulate various data pieces that your public method creates during its work. If you simply test just this public method and wont test private methods your approach is not TDD and unit tests wont ever show where the problem is, they will simply indicate that SOMETHING SOMEWHERE is wrong. which is not enough.

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub, I see your point but then it comes down to at what level you wish to test. I only test the interface to my classes. If they work, that's good enough for me to have confidence in my code *and* have the ability to change my private methods without having to refactor any tests. Following link explains that POV pretty good but as with all things, it is in the eye of the beholder. http://www.thehackerchickblog.com/2008/07/your-unit-tests-should-mind-their-own.html

Answer (score 2):

You are right that using reflection has much the same pitfalls as using the PrivateObject pattern. A better solution is to avoid trying to specifically test private methods.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I cannot avoid testing private methods its is the requirement. so wanted to chose between reflection and PrivateObject with proper understanding

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the **[Gallio/MbUnit](http://gallio.org)** testing framework, you might consider the built-in [**Mirror**](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3amirror) API.

> Sometimes, the most obvious way to write a test is by accessing non-public state or behaviors. It may not be the best way to write the test but it may seem like the simplest solution for the time being. MbUnit provides a couple of classes to help access non-public members.